# YiiMailer : Unable to view "html" emails

Tags: html, email, yii

I am using YiiMailer service with following

```
eturn array(
'viewPath' => 'webroot.themes.abound.views.mail',
'layoutPath' => 'webroot.themes.abound.views.layouts.mail',
'baseDirPath' => 'webroot.images.mail', //note: 'webroot' alias in console apps may not be the same as in web apps
'savePath' => 'webroot.assets.mail',
'testMode' => false,
'layout' => 'mail', // name of the file 
'CharSet' => 'iso-8859-1',
'AltBody' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'You need an HTML capable viewer to read this message.'),
'language' => array(
    'authenticate' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.'),
    'connect_host' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.'),
    'data_not_accepted' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'SMTP Error: Data not accepted.'),
    'empty_message' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Message body empty'),
    'encoding' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Unknown encoding: '),
    'execute' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Could not execute: '),
    'file_access' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Could not access file: '),
    'file_open' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'File Error: Could not open file: '),
    'from_failed' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'The following From address failed: '),
    'instantiate' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Could not instantiate mail function.'),
    'invalid_address' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Invalid address'),
    'mailer_not_supported' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', ' mailer is not supported.'),
    'provide_address' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'You must provide at least one recipient email address.'),
    'recipients_failed' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: '),
    'signing' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Signing Error: '),
    'smtp_connect_failed' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'SMTP Connect() failed.'),
    'smtp_error' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'SMTP server error: '),
    'variable_set' => Yii::t('YiiMailer', 'Cannot set or reset variable: ')
),

$mail = new YiiMailer();
        $mail->setView('contact');
        $mail->setData(
                        array(  'message' => "Sample Message", 
                                'name' => 'John Doe', 
                                'description' => 'Contact form'
                            ));
        $mail->setFrom('admin@website.com', 'website');
        $mail->setTo($_POST['logEmail']);
        $mail->setLayout('basic');
        $mail->setSubject('Mail subject');
        if ($mail->send()) {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
        } else {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Error while sending email: '.$mail->getError());
        }
        /////// Email Code over

        $model->Email=$_POST['logEmail'];
        $model->Password=$_POST['logPassword'];
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
        {
            //echo ""
        }
        else
        {
            echo "User Name or Password seems to be incorrect, Try again";
            exit();
        }
    }
```

I am using the following template to send email >http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates

Not sure why in the email , I am receiving plain text and not html rich emails .. although in the template , I am referring a correct css file with correct path.
Can anyone let me know if I am missing anything please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

YiiMailer extends PHPMailer, so looking at the PHPMailer class we should be able to do the following to achieve an html email:

```
$mail->Body("Sample Message");
$mail->IsHtml(true);
$mail->setData(
    array(
            'name' => 'John Doe', 
            'description' => 'Contact form'
        ));
```